# Waiting data from socket using ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, sockets, casting, streaming

I'm waiting for the data on the stream such a strange way... Because i think throwing exceptions each time stream tries `readObject()` is not a good idea. That's why I use `PushBackInputStream` and read just one `byte` from that stream each 10 ms.

```
@Override
public void run() {
try {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
        clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
    oos.flush();
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    PushbackInputStream pis = new PushbackInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    while (true) {
    int tempByte = -1;
    if ((tempByte = pis.read()) == -1) {
        sleep(10);
    } else {
        pis.unread(tempByte);
        ArrayList<Object> arrList = (ArrayList<Object>) ois.readObject();
        int command = (Integer) arrList.get(0);
        if (command == CommandDescriptor.ADD_STRING.getCode()) {
        String tempStr = (String) arrList.get(1);
        boolean result = Server.colleciton.add(tempStr);
        if (result) {
            oos.writeInt(1);
            oos.flush();
        } else {
            oos.writeInt(0);
            oos.flush();
        }
        } else if (command == CommandDescriptor.REMOVE_STRING.getCode()) {
        ...
```

I do something wrong with streams... I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.ObjectStreamClass cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
at com.rizhov.main.ClientHandler.run(ClientHandler.java:39)
```

At that part of code:

```
ArrayList<Object> arrList = (ArrayList<Object>) ois.readObject();
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any better solution to wait a data.

UPDATE:

```
ArrayList<Object> arrList = null;
    for (;;) {
        try {
        arrList = ((ArrayList<Object>) ois.readObject());
        break;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    int command = (Integer) arrList.get(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only wrap a Stream once. If you wrap it multiple times you are more likely to get confused than it be useful.

Once a stream has closed it won't re-open so reading a character to check if the stream has finished and discarding it is not very useful. Sleeping when the operation would block anyway is not very useful either.

Instead of using `Integer` codes I would use enum values. This will be cleaner and you will be able to use a switch statement.

Comment: yeah. double stream wrapping was a mistake, now I fixed my code that way (above)... that works but I guess that's too slow for real data processing...

Comment: It might be too slow, but it might be more than fast enough. It depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for any of this peeking and sleeping. It is a complete waste of your time and energy and of CPU time and space.

All Java streams block while there is no data. They block for exactly the correct amount of time, too, not 10ms or whatever at a time, and without wasting CPU cycles in spinning as you are doing.

You don't have to do any of that yourself in any way shape or form. Just call `readObject()`.

And never ignore an `IOException`.

Comment: Do you mean my stream will be waiting for new data? Does `readObject()` throw any exception if there is no data in that stream?

Comment: @Pavel I not only meant it, I said it. So does the Javadoc. It will block until data arrives. Just call it. It will throw `EOFException` when the peer closes the connection. It's easy.

Comment: Thanks, @EJP! I don't know how I missed that!